# Printing an array to HTML in asp.net

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net

Im new to asp.net but experienced in php. I would like to dynamically generate some HTML from an object array in the code behind.

In PHP I would do something like:

Supposed Code behind:

```
<?php

   $items = array('1'=>'dog', '2'=>'chair', '3'=>'bruce springsteen');

?>
```

Then in the markup:

```
<? foreach($items as $key => $value ){?>

    <div class="html-markup">
      key: <?=$key?>, value: <?=$value?>
    </div>

<?}?>
```

How do I do this in asp.net?

Code behind:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM aTable";
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,  new SqlConnection(ConnectionString));
DataTable dtControls = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dtControls);

foreach(DataRow thisRow in dtControls.Rows){
   Console.WriteLine(thisRow["item"].ToString());
}
```

Id like to print the contents of dtControls to HTML

Comment: You might want to look at ASP.NET MVC and how the razor syntax handles this. You can do something like @foreach (var item in Model) { ... } and render that out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: What framework and view engine do you use? MVC? Razor?

Comment: its definitely not Razor. pretty sure its not MVC either. just regular .net

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@{
string[] members = {"Jani", "Hege", "Kai", "Jim"};
int i = Array.IndexOf(members, "Kai")+1;
int len = members.Length;
string x = members[2-1];
}
<html>
<body>
<h3>Members</h3>
@foreach (var person in members)
{
<p>@person</p>
}
<p>The number of names in Members are @len</p>
<p>The person at position 2 is @x</p>
<p>Kai is now in position @i</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is in the Razor framework, correct? I dont have access to that

Comment: how are you passing the data from your controller to your view?

Answer (score 0):

Using WebForms ? Use a Repeater. Here's a good intro: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/

Learn more: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/overview